# How to delete a row in Sq Lite? [Android App Development]

Tags: android, sqlite

Inserted a Students details in a table which includes Name, Id, Email and phone and it's shown in a ListView.
When I click on a List View item, it goes to the next page, which show corresponding students details. In that page i want to insert a button and when click that button whole details of that students which means that corresponding row will delete. How it is Possible.

### Java Class

```
Button deletest;
    del=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.del);
    deletest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            DBUserAdapter dbUser = new DBUserAdapter(getApplicationContext());
            dbUser.open();
            String data=del.getText().toString();
            dbUser.delete(data);
            return;


        }
    });
```

### DB Helper Class

```
public Cursor delete(String data) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(
                "DELETE * FROM addresstable where studentid=" + data, null);

        return mCursor;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `rawQuery()`:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery(
            "DELETE * FROM addresstable where studentid=" + data, null);
```

`rawQuery()` is valid for... **queries** (which means `SELECT`).
For SQL **commands** (like `INSERT`, `DELETE`, `UPDATE`, ...) use `execSQL()`:

```
Cursor mCursor = db.execSQL(
            "DELETE * FROM addresstable where studentid=" + data);
```